# Select Case True in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, select-case

I have the following select case where I want to do some checks on what a string contains and call some functions for each case. But it seems that if multiple conditions are true it considers only the first condition. The problem is I have about 113 different cases.

Do I have to use an if statement for each case?

```
   Select Case True
          Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" S:")
'Do something
          Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" C:")
'Do something
          Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" *S")
'Do something
          Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" *C")
'Do something
          Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" CC")
'Do something
          Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" SS")
    End Select
```

Comment: @Oded completly different stuff, in the end they will be used to generate a dynamc sql command which returns a table used to graph data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Case True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794036/select-case-true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how select case is defined. Using a sequence of If statements would work.

Consider a table-driven solution (Pseudocode):

```
For Each pat In patterns
  If command contains pattern.pat
    perform pattern.action
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but what about

```
dim tempCommand as string = command.ToUpper()
dim match as boolean = true

while match andalso tempCommand.length > 0
    select case true
        Case tempCommand.Contains(" S:")
            'Do something
            'then do this    
            tempCommand = tempCommand.replace(" S:","")
        Case tempCommand.Contains(" C:")
            'Do something
            'then do this
            tempCommand = tempCommand.replace(" C:","")
        Case tempCommand.Contains(" *S")
            'Do something
            'then do this
            tempCommand = tempCommand.replace(" *S","")
        Case tempCommand.Contains(" *C")
            'Do something    
            'then do this
            tempCommand = tempCommand.replace(" *C","")
        Case tempCommand.Contains(" CC")
            'Do something
            'then do this
            tempCommand = tempCommand.replace(" CC","")
        Case command.ToUpper.Contains(" SS")
            'then do this
            tempCommand = tempCommand.replace(" SS","")    
        case else match = false
    end select
end while
```

I'm assuming that based on the various criteria you are performing different actions, so I'm not sure how you would do the "perform pattern.action" unless that is a way of doing code dynamically that I don't know about and would be totally cool if it can be done.

My suggestion does destroy the command, which is why I'm using a temporary holding variable so that the original command isn't lost, in case you need it further in the code.