# Use VBA to copy all visible and non-empty cells in a range

Tags: excel, copy, constants, visible, vba

After filtering, I want to copy all visible and non-empty cells (the cells which contain text). For some reason, my current code isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S2:S5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
```

Comment: "For some reason, my current code isn't working.", perhaps you could elaborate further...

Answer (score 3):

Full admission that I did not try your code, but you can also try the following

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S2:S5000")
    Application.Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
                       .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)).Copy
End With
```

Making the open ended assumption that the reason for copying is to paste somewhere else, you can update the above code by using

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S2:S5000")
    Application.Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)).Copy _
               Destination:= Sheets("destSheet").Range("destRange")
End With
```

Comment: "so they probably can't be used together like you have done", why not - did you try it?  Works fine for me.  Your code selects all the visible cells whether they are constants or not.  I think he wants all the visible cells that are also constants.

Comment: double whammy, i didn't check and it was incorrect. thanks for callin me out @Reafidy; I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

i need to copy all not empty, also one if there are not visible, but i find only this tread for. Eventualy is it usefull for someone...

```vb
Sub button_Klick()
On Error GoTo wrong
Dim r As Range
Dim sel As Range
'Dim f As Range
Dim text
Set r = Range("e4") 'd9:d1954

Set sel = Range(r)

'sel.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy 'this will copy all, allso with formula =""

'Set f = Range("d9")'define first for union

For Each cell In sel.Cells
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
       'Set f = Union(f, cell)
       text = text & vbCrLf & cell.Value
    End If
Next cell
'f.Select
'f.Copy 'will copy allso all empty
Clipboard (text)
MsgBox "Ready!" & vbCrLf & "Text is in the clipboard...", vbInformation, "Ready! Text is in the clipboard..."
Exit Sub

wrong:
  
  MsgBox "Error " & vbCrLf & "Number: " & Err.Number & _
  vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        
End Sub

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard/60896244#60896244
Function Clipboard$(Optional s$)
    Dim v: v = s  'Cast to variant for 64-bit VBA support
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
        Select Case True
            Case Len(s): .setData "text", v
            Case Else:   Clipboard = .GetData("text")
        End Select
    End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Don't use `cell.Value <> ""` but rather `IsEmpty(cell)`.  Also `Set sel = Range(r)` does nothing. Did you mean to write `sel = r.Resize(1900,1)`?