# VBA copies Columns including all blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

This VBA works. It makes a new worksheet, and then copies every and all cells in column(45) including the blank ones. How do I get it to not copy the blank/cells or the ones that contain no value? I know once the everything is consolidated into the new worksheet I can use the filter function for blanks but I want to skip that step.

```
Sub merge()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ShM As Worksheet, i&, z&
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Set Sh = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Sh.Name = "consolidated"
    For Each ShM In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ShM.Name <> Sh.Name Then
            i = ShM.Cells(Rows.Count, 45).End(xlUp).Row
            ShM.Activate: ShM.Range(Cells(1, 45), Cells(i, 45)).Copy
            Sh.Activate: Sh.Cells(z, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next ShM
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of data are you copying?  Numbers or formulas?  You can use a version of `.SpecialCells()` to get only non-blank cells.  Use `xlCellTypeFormulas` or `xlCellTypeConstants` depending on what you have.  You can also `Union` those together if you have both types of data.  You would use `SpecialCells` on the range before copying: `ShM.Range(...).SpecialCells(...).Copy`.

Comment: This is also related to [this one which loops through checking <>""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822225/copy-non-blank-cells-from-range-to-range) and [this which uses SpecialCells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625468/use-vba-to-copy-all-visible-and-non-empty-cells-in-a-range)

Comment: } else if (vSym == "FEYE") {
     addBand( 35.25, PS_SOLID, 1, Color.RGB(0,255,0), 80001 );
    addBand( 43, PS_SOLID, 1, Color.RGB(255,59,56), 90002 );

Comment: that's what it is copying tons of those lines haha

Comment: I saw that post the other day, I just don't know how to merge the two VBA's I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses *arrays* in order to obtain the original values and to eliminate *blank values* (from blank cells or as result of a formula). It also enters the resulting data in column **A** in the *consolidated* Wsh, leaving a blank row between worksheets data to ensure no overlap of takes place, and a two blank rows of separation when a worksheet only has *blank values*. Also using a constant to identify the targeted column *(column 5 in this sample, just changed as required)*

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Wsh_MergeColDataFromAllOterWorksheets()
Const kCol As Byte = 5
Dim Sh As Worksheet, ShM As Worksheet, i As Long, z As Long
Dim aAryInput As Variant, vAryOutput() As Variant
Dim vCllVal As Variant
Dim l As Long

    Rem Add New Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Set Sh = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

    Rem Delete Consolidate Wsh if present
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("consolidated").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

    Rem Add New Worksheet
    Sh.Name = "consolidated"

    z = 1
    For Each ShM In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ShM
            If .Name <> Sh.Name Then

                Rem Get Last Row
                i = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

                Rem Set Input Array
                aAryInput = Empty
                aAryInput = .Range(.Cells(1, kCol), .Cells(i, kCol))

                Rem Initiate & Size Output Array
                Erase vAryOutput
                ReDim Preserve vAryOutput(i)

                Rem Get Non Blank Cells Value
                l = 0
                For Each vCllVal In aAryInput
                    If WorksheetFunction.Trim(vCllVal) <> Empty Then
                        l = 1 + l
                        vAryOutput(l) = vCllVal
                End If: Next

            If l <> 0 Then
                Rem Erase Blank Values in Output Array
                ReDim Preserve vAryOutput(l)
                vAryOutput = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vAryOutput)

                Rem Set NonBlank Values in Wsh "consolidated" (Column 1)
                Sh.Cells(z, 1).Resize(l).Value = vAryOutput
            End If

            Rem Set Next Row
            z = 1 + z + l

    End If: End With: Next ShM
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work. It did the same as the above VBA i first listed. It still left those extra blanks at the bottom. I do not know why. They do have a formula in them but the blanks aren't being used at all.

Comment: HI Trosky6708, please let know what did not worked, the code above was tested, I'm interested to know why you are not getting the expected results. What are you getting?.

Comment: There's nothing really funky about the sheets I am using it on. Description of file: File size Corner to Corner A:2000 - AS:2000 there are a few blank columns in there for spacers. Each sheet is identical except for the #'s I input. It is only using one array to filter non blank cells for I2000:k2000 that gets output to M2000:O2000. Columns 45 only contain data up until row 500, but they auto update so the number varies, which leaves an extra 1500 cells. Your script pastes the correct data but does not eliminate these extra 1500+ cells. All cells in column 45 contain formula =X584&" "&AL584&""

Comment: The formula in column 45 =X584&" "&AL584&"" which extends down to row 2000 displays a bunch lines that look like this: "  addBand( 35.75, PS_SOLID, 1, Color.RGB(0,255,0), 80001 );" AND like I said currently they only go to row 500 but they autoupdate so the number of rows used will increase over time. So tomorrow there could be "  addBand( 35.75, PS_SOLID, 1, Color.RGB(0,255,0), 80001 );" 600 of these lines in column 45. That's why I have the formula extending down to the 2000th row.

Comment: I am getting the correct data, but it leaves the extra 1500+ blanks from each worksheet. Then it pastes the next data from the next worksheet along with it's extra 1500 blanks.

Comment: Trosky6708 thanks for your feed back, it seems to be something specific with the data in your worksheet, (i.e. formatting, etc) can you place your worksheet somewhere in the internet so I can give a look and provide a full solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes one moment google drives or something & post the link as quick as possible

Comment: Actually it worked, was able to download your file. Let me look into it and will come back to you. Cheers.

Comment: For this excel file make sure the Selected Column to copy is 44 u'll see what happens. It works with column 5 but not 44

Comment: Thanks. I was about to tell that column 45 is blank

Comment: The problem was that some cells have the Value _" " (blank spaces)_ which I did not expected.
Nevertheless the code is adjusted to take care of that, just change this line `If vCllVal <> Empty Then` with this `If WorksheetFunction.Trim(vCllVal) <> Empty Then` Remember that its required to have the following at the top of the module `Option Explicit` and `Option Base 1`
_Seems that it was a good idea to have the column to copy as a constant._ Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but one of the simplest is to copy the data over then delete those blanks:

```
Sub merge()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ShM As Worksheet, i&, z& *Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    z = 1
    Set Sh = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Sh.Name = "consolidated"
    For Each ShM In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ShM.Name <> Sh.Name Then
            i = ShM.Cells(Rows.Count, 45).End(xlUp).Row
            ShM.Activate: ShM.Range(Cells(1, 45), Cells(i, 45)).Copy
            Sh.Activate: Sh.Cells(z, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            z = z + 1
        End If
        For i = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count,45).End(xlUp).Row to 1 Step -1
            If Sh.Cells(i,45).Value = "" Then Sh.Cells(i,45).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
    Next ShM
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with this, but deleting the `EntireRow` just to avoid blanks is a bit overkill and not appropriate if the other worksheet has data already.  I would `Delete` only the `Cell` if you really want to use this approach.  Less collateral damage.

Comment: Not working, Fixed the syntax error with *Application.ScreenUpdating = 0. Then it gives me an error with Sh.Activate: Sh.Cells(z, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Not sure if your current code would work either.  You are using `z` without setting its value.  By default it will have a value `z=0` which is not a valid row number to give to `Cells`.

Comment: I know that deleting the entire row seems like overkill, but from the code (copying row by row) and the current workaround (filtering) it seems that this is essentially what's desired.  It looks like z was just a counter to track the number of rows that have already been copied.  I don't know how it was working as OP states with the beginning "This VBA works."  Is there some code missing?  You may have to add in a line after your paste of: z = z +1 to work.  As well as setting z = 1 to initialize.

Comment: The code I originally posted does work, and have been using it many times . I just want the blanks gone lol

Comment: Did you add the increment z line I mentioned in the last comment?  As well as the initializing of z?