# VBA in Excel 2010, Send Variable to windows clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following simple, Excel Macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
x = Selection.Address(False, False)
y = ActiveSheet.Name
Z = "''" & y & "'!" & x

End Sub
```

Is it possible to send the string named Z to the windows clipboard?

Comment: There's a few answers here that will help. I'm kind of partial to the second one with the self-contained function and the late binding to the MSForms library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked amazingly!  I tried searching before but didnt come accross that solution.  Also, just so anyway searching for this knows, you do have to add a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library in Tools - References in the VBE.

Answer (score 0):

Code that works after using:

[Excel VBA code to copy a specific string to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard)

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
x = Selection.Address(False, False)
y = ActiveSheet.Name
Z = "''" & y & "'!" & x

With New MSForms.DataObject
    .SetText Z
    .PutInClipboard
End With

End Sub
```