# Extra double-quote character when C/P'ing out of Excel

Tags: excel, char, clipboard, plaintext

Stackoverflow folk!

I am having a funny double-quote issue with Excel.  I am attempting to generate some XML code in a cell that I then copy/paste into a plain-text editor to save (in this case, Notepad).

So, these work as expected:

`="hello ""world"", folks!"`

and

`="hello "&CHAR(34)&"world"&CHAR(34)&", folks!"`

each output `hello "world", folks!` as expected, and copy/paste into Notepad just fine.

However, as soon as I add a line break, as in the following two examples:

`="hello ""world"", folks!"&CHAR(13)`

or

`="hello "&CHAR(34)&"world"&CHAR(34)&", folks!"&CHAR(13)`

The output looks fine in Excel, but upon copy/paste into Notepad, I get a problematic result

`"hello ""world"", folks!"`

I obviously can't have random extra double-quotes floating around in my final XML, but I can't see a way to get my output without them.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like the copy-paste is designed to allow for escaping new lines in CSV/tab-delimited content: you'll see the same behaviour if you add a tab The quotes are added because there's a newline/tab in the text.  Why do you need to add the line breaks?  Just for readability?

Comment: This was just some sample code to illustrate the problem; the final XML is quite long, and wouldn't be maintainable without good spacing and  indentation.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way around this without some VBA for example. Something like   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard