# How to copy without losing information?

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I am trying to copy a text from a range, but if someone press "ESC" or anything else, this information is lost.

I copy with this macro:

```
Sub Copiar_Reposta()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Planilha1.Select
Range("A45").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Application.SendKeys "{F2}", True
Application.SendKeys "+{HOME}", True
Application.SendKeys "^C", True
Application.SendKeys "{ESC}", True

Planilha3.Select

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Immediately the "NUM LOCK" turns off, and after trying to fix it, this macro stopped working as well.

Is there a way to copy the information from a cell without losing it after?
Or, is there a way to fix my macro that stopped working suddenly.

Copy like this: 
[image: Copying with "F2" and "CTRL + C"]

Comment: What do you want to do with the copied text? `SendKeys` can be unreliable. More context would be helpful to properly answer your question.

Comment: you dont need to use `SendKeys` to copy a value... you can just write `Planilha3.Range("A45").Value = Planilha1.Range("A45").Value` instead of all of that code (assuming that's your destination cell)

Comment: My destination it's not in Excel, that's why I need copy from "inside" that cell.

Comment: In that case, you can use this function to directly copy something to the clipboard https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336423/2727437

Comment: What should I do ? **Range("A45").Select 
CopyText Selection.Text** after insert CopyText macro ? @Marcucciboy2

Comment: `CopyText Planilha1.Range("A45").Text`

Comment: I did it what you said, and after paste it gets two blocks, not the text. Like this: �
I dont know how to insert Picture here to show you.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe give this a try? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486033/2727437

Comment: I searched as well, that problem is a bug that occurs when "File Explorer" is open, I closed and it worked, but I'd like to have another code for backup.
Everyone say that we could use copy to API Windows, so in your link, where do I set the text ? @Marcucciboy2

Comment: To include this you actually would keep the code that you already have and include this code in a new module. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/

Comment: Great, it worked !! **You're the best, thank you!!**

Comment: That's great news, I'm glad I could help and that you beat me to some of the research haha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark the question as answered, I solved the problem with the help from @Marcucciboy2, using this link [Text To Clipboard in VBA Windows 10 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue/35486033#35486033) and this link [Excel VBA code to copy a specific string to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard/25336423#25336423) to copy information to my clipboard, when I searched the problem is a bug that occurs when "File Explorer" is open, I closed and it worked. But I'm not using this function anymore.