# Copy last sent email from outlook 2016 to memory

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2016

I have used the code below on outlook 2010 without any glicthes but with 2016 outlook it does nothing and gives no error.

```
sub copylastsenttomem ()
 Dim objSentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim objSentItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outForward As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objNS As Namespace
Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder


Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

  Set outForward = objFolder.Items(1).Forward
 'Set outForward = objFolder.Items(1)
'outForward.Display

 Dim M As MailItem, Buf As MSForms.DataObject
Set M = outForward


Set Buf = New MSForms.DataObject
Buf.SetText M.body
Buf.PutInClipboard


end sub
```

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue) helps you.

Comment: Do you have any items in the `Sent Items` folder?

Answer (score 1):

In the code, you assume that the Sent Items folder has any items inside:

```
  Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
  Set outForward = objFolder.Items(1).Forward
```

Make sure that a folder contains at least one item to forward.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Do you get any errors?