Excel Macro Copy and Paste Stops Working after initial use, how can I fix?
Hi have an excel workbook that I've been using for a few months, with several copy and paste buttons. Only recently have they stopped working after about 2 mins in of using excel all I get are these ��. When I load the spreadsheet they all work normally, but a while later they stop. Any advice?
I've tried resaving, close opening, restarting. The code works fine upon initial use, it just stops after a bit.
My code for each button looks as follows:
Sub CopyKennelGuidelinesTextToClipboard()
    Dim DataObj As Object
    Set DataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    DataObj.SetText "ADV GST KENNEL GUIDELINES AND RESTRICTIONS"
    DataObj.PutInClipboard
    Set DataObj = Nothing
End Sub

I've tried resaving, close opening, restarting. The code works fine upon initial use, it just stops after a bit.

This is a known problem and this approach is not reliable.  Alternative here using Windows API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue
