# Excel Macro Paste a value in Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I would like to create a loop to paste "online" in column N when the value is blank.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible.

Comment: do you have a sample or reference?

Comment: I have this script already:
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("medtour_enquiries").Range("N1:N1000000").AutoFilter 1, "="

My next step is to paste "online" on the filtered column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I assume you know the last line in column N, otherwise you will have to change it to a do-while loop

```
Sub LoopN()
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
n = cells(rows.count, "N").end(xlup).row
For i = 1 To n
If Cells(i, 14).Value = "" Then Cells(i, 14).Value = "online"
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A fairly standard method for returning the last populated cell in a column would be looking from the bottom up. Something like `n = cells(rows.count, "N").end(xlup).row`

Comment: You are right Jeeped. I've edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Here's mine:

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("medtour_enquiries").Range("N1:N1000000").AutoFilter 1, "="
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("medtour_enquiries").Cells(2, 14).Copy
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("medtour_enquiries").Range("N2:N1000000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("medtour_enquiries").AutoFilterMode = False

What I want now is instead of copying the cell value:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("medtour_enquiries").Cells(2, 14).Copy

I want to copy a string example = MyString = "online"

Comment: It is more complicated to store a string in the clipboard, then simply putting it in a cell and then referencing it whenever you need. But if you insist then try reading here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard [