# Copy Multiple label and textbox in excel vb

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is the copy button I honestly do not know where to start I tried google but with no results, I know it is a messed up codes but please bear with me. Some of the codes I just copied from the internet like the message box, I hope to make the Copy button replicate the Ctrl+C and when I Ctrl+V to notepad all will show. You can check the image that I have posted.

[image: Userform]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to continue?", vbYesNoCancel + vbInformation, "Application Message")

If Answer = vbYes Then Else Exit Sub

    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox6.Text = ""
    TextBox7.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""
    TextBox9.Text = ""
    TextBox10.Text = ""
    TextBox11.Text = ""
---------------------------------------
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  <--COPY button

Label1.text&""&TextBox1.text Select
Label2.text&""&TextBox2.text Select
and so forth
Select.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following macro allows you to send a string of text to the clipboard:

```
Sub CopyText(Text As String)
    'VBA Macro using late binding to copy text to clipboard.
    'By Justin Kay, 8/15/2014
    Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
    Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
    MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Disclaimer: this is not mine, but it comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336423/3111149).

Once you have added this macro to your project, your Copy Button's code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  <--COPY button

    Dim stringToCopy As String
    stringToCopy = Label1.Text & ": " & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine
    stringToCopy = stringToCopy & Label2.Text & ": " & TextBox2.Text & vbNewLine
    'etc.

    'then you send this string to the clipboard:
    CopyText stringToCopy

End Sub
```

Your clipboard now contains your string that you can paste anywhere in your computer.

Comment: thank you @Matteo NNZ,
I tried the code you provided, and it worked. But it only copies one set of string

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim stringToCopy As String

    
    stringToCopy = Label1 & " " & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine
    stringToCopy = Label2 & " " & TextBox2.Text & vbNewLine
    stringToCopy = Label3 & " " & TextBox3.Text & vbNewLine
    
    CopyText stringToCopy

End Sub

Comment: @Mr.Willing2Learn I've posted this answer more than 4 years ago, it's a bit late to ask for feedback now :D