# Copy in Access using VBA

Tags: database, vba, forms, ms-access, report

I created a copy button in an Access form to copy the Data in the fields that users enter so they can paste it in an internal system.

I created VBA code "on the click:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
     On Error GoTo Err_cmdDuplicate_Click
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

     Exit_cmdDuplicate_Click:
     Exit Sub

     Err_cmdDuplicate_Click:
         MsgBox Err.Description
         Resume Exit_cmdDuplicate_Click

 End Sub
```

I am having 2 problems:
 it copies all the data with the headers but pastes it vertically rather than horizontally. I guess it needs to be formatted. I have to add since the code was grabbing everything in the form even the information that I didn't want. I created a query then a report based on the query then made the copy button with the code behind it.

Comment: Where is the data being pasted to?  You can set the clipboard text directly via VBA, so you can select which data fields get copied:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard

Comment: As @TimWilliams says - it matters what the destination is. Different methods for text vs Excel. Excel allows you to use CopyFromRecordset without header, Text might have to be coded in a loop to form a string for the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

this is the code
Private Sub cmdCopy_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdDuplicate_Click

'Copies values from agent entered data fields into
'required format for TAS and copies to
'system clipboard.

'control name and type are as follows:
'CboTeam
'CboTax
'TboCallBack
'TboCaller
'TboBusName
'CboAuthType
'TboAuthID
'CboContact
'TboDetail
'TboBal
'TboDelqs

Application.Echo False
Me.PasteBox.Visible = True

Me!PasteBox.Value = _
"Team:  " & Me!CboTeam & vbNewLine & _
"Tax Type: " & Me!CboTax & vbNewLine & _
"Phone:  " & Me!TboCallBack & vbNewLine & _
"Caller:  " & Me!TboCaller & vbNewLine & _
"Business Name:  " & Me!TboBusnAME & vbNewLine & _
"Authentication Method:  " & Me!CboAuthType & vbNewLine & _
"Authentication ID:  " & Me!TboAuthID & vbNewLine & _
"Contact Reason:  " & Me!CboContact & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & _
"Call Detail:" & vbNewLine & _
Me!TboDetail & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & _
"Balance:  " & Me!TboBal & vbNewLine & _
"Delinquent Periods:  " & Me!TboDelqs

Me.PasteBox.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

Me.cmdcopy.SetFocus

Me.PasteBox.Visible = False
Application.Echo True

Exit_cmdDuplicate_Click:
    Exit Sub
Application.Echo True

Err_cmdDuplicate_Click:
     MsgBox Err.Description
Application.Echo True
    Resume Exit_cmdDuplicate_Click
Application.Echo True
End Sub