# Copy text from a textbox to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy text from a Text Box to the clipboard.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With New MSForms.DataObject
        .SetText TextBox1.Text
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

I get

> "Run-time error '424' Object required.

Debugging causes `.setText TextBox1.Text` to highlight and say "MyData <Object variable or with block variable not set".

Comment: See answer below, you have to instantiate that DataObject (create) with a variable (pointer to physical location), not work with it directly.

Comment: You may have renamed the default `TextBox1.Text` to another (Name) e.g. txtFooBar.Text while coding. So, the object name is different in code and GUI design.

Comment: True, because it works your way.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14226925/8716187

```
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

'Put a string in the clipboard
DataObj.SetText Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").TextBox1.Text 'name of your textbox here
DataObj.PutInClipboard

'Get a string from the clipboard
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
Debug.Print DataObj.GetText
```

** Tested and working, no scope problems here though as Textbox, Control Button, Worksheet Code all in the same scope - you may need to describe the location of your objects
[image]
-WWC

I tested your version, it also worked, be sure your TextBox1 is what you think it is.  How is it created, if at runtime it may not the the number (name) you think it is.

This also compiles and runs without error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    With New MSForms.DataObject

    'Put a string in the clipboard
    .SetText TextBox1.Text 'name of your textbox here
    .PutInClipboard

    'Get a string from the clipboard
    .GetFromClipboard
    Debug.Print .GetText

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should surely work without any problem

`With Me.TextBox1 .SelStart = 0 .SelLength = Len(.Text) .Copy End With`

Answer (score 0):

I found the only thing that works is the [Microsoft solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/send-information-to-the-clipboard). Copy the code and paste into a new module (called "*ClipBoard*") and, voila, reliable clipboard functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me. Its will be put all text in Textbox1 to clipboard so its can be use at another application via paste command.

```
TextBox1.SetFocus
```

`TextBox1.SelStart = 0`

`TextBox1.SelLength = Len(TextBox1.Text)`

`TextBox1.Copy`