# Copy the Cell Itself to Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

How can I copy the certain cell in clipboard.
This is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
Dim str1 As String

clipboard.SetText ""
clipboard.PutInClipboard
    
clipboard.SetText ActiveSheet.Range("G11")
clipboard.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

But in clip board the Icon that I want is like Excel Cell Copied not text copied.

Like this picture

[image]

Comment: Does `ActiveSheet.Range("G11").Copy` do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard/60896244#60896244

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you its working. How about this one once I clicked my Button there's a "True" in clipboard and that text I dont want to put in my Clipboard. Thank you