# Trouble with copy-pasting a web page through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble selecting the entire webpage, copying it, and pasting onto the excel spreadsheet using the code below through VBA. Also, I'm sure I haven't properly put instructions for the copy-paste procedure.

References for VBA:

[image]

```
Sub Horse10()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument

 
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
          
    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.racingandsports.com.au/Jockey/GetJockeyStats?jockeyIdStr=18658&discipline=T&season=All%20Seasons&hemisphere=S&_=1629813279071", False
        .send

        '''The issue starts here

        http.SelectAll.Copy
        ws.Cells(2, 10).Select.Paste
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: can't quite remember but feel like you have to wait for the response to come back from the send

Answer (score 0):

I used the clipboard function from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896244/1490783) to get the data to the clipboard, then `ws.Paste` to paste it in the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Horse10()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    'Dim html As New HTMLDocument

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.racingandsports.com.au/Jockey/GetJockeyStats?jockeyIdStr=18658&discipline=T&season=All%20Seasons&hemisphere=S&_=1629813279071", False
        .send

        '''The issue starts here
        Call Clipboard(http.responseText)

        ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Cells(2, 10)
    End With
End Sub

Function Clipboard$(Optional s$)
    Dim v: v = s  'Cast to variant for 64-bit VBA support
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        With .parentWindow.clipboardData
            Select Case True
                Case Len(s): .setData "text", v
                Case Else:   Clipboard = .GetData("text")
            End Select
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, although it includes hyperlinks.

Comment: You could use `PasteSpecial` with the `NoHtmlFormatting` parameter set to `True` to get rid of all formatting and links. See https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial for more.