# Navigate to URL in current Tab in Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

The code below can be used to navigate to URL in current Tab in Chrome.
`UIA` is used for finding the Chrome Tab.
But the new URL is set by pasting from clipboard, which is not good enough.

1. get to restore the clipboard content
2. get to switch the focus back to excel
   So my question is, **is there a method in `UIA` to set the value to a control?**

Or if there are other good method to do this, your help will be appreciated.
Other method I've considered:

1. `shell`,  slow, has to open new tab
2. `selenium`, open chrome in debug mode, not the normal mode, will make the work-flow un-contineous.

```vb
Function GetChrome(ByRef uia As CUIAutomation) As IUIAutomationElement
    
    
    'Dim uia As New CUIAutomation
    Dim el_Desktop As IUIAutomationElement
    Set el_Desktop = uia.GetRootElement
    
    Dim el_ChromeWins As IUIAutomationElementArray
    Dim el_ChromeWin As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim cnd_ChromeWin As IUIAutomationCondition

    ' check the window with class name as "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"
    Set cnd_ChromeWin = uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
    Set el_ChromeWins = el_Desktop.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, cnd_ChromeWin)
    Set el_ChromeWin = Nothing
    
    
    If el_ChromeWins.Length = 0 Then
        Debug.Print """Chrome_WidgetWin_1"" not found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim count_ChromeWins As Integer
    For count_ChromeWins = 0 To el_ChromeWins.Length - 1
        CurWinTitle = el_ChromeWins.GetElement(count_ChromeWins).CurrentName
        If (InStr(1, CurWinTitle, "Chrome")) Then
            Set el_ChromeWin = el_ChromeWins.GetElement(count_ChromeWins)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
    If el_ChromeWin Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No Chrome Window Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set GetChrome = el_ChromeWin
End Function


Sub Chrome_NavigateTo()

    Dim strURL As String
    strURL = "https://google.com/"
    Clipboard strURL
    
    Dim uia As New CUIAutomation
    Dim el_ChromeWin As IUIAutomationElement
    Set el_ChromeWin = GetChrome(uia)
    Debug.Print "1-" & el_ChromeWin.CurrentName
    
    If el_ChromeWin Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Chrome doe NOT exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    Dim cnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set cnd = uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "地址和搜索栏")
    
    Dim AddressBar As IUIAutomationElement
    Set AddressBar = el_ChromeWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, cnd)
    Debug.Print AddressBar.CurrentName
    Debug.Print AddressBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId)
    AddressBar.SetFocus
    SendKeys "^a"
    SendKeys "{DEL}"
    SendKeys "^V"
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub


Function Clipboard$(Optional s$)
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard/60896244#60896244
    Dim v: v = s  'Cast to variant for 64-bit VBA support
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
        Select Case True
            Case Len(s): .setData "text", v
            Case Else:   Clipboard = .GetData("text")
        End Select
    End With
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The original idea is that, I got a list of *.mhtml files in a column of Excel Worksheet and woudl like to preview these files one by one when selecting the corresponding cell.
Chrome open and renders these file faster than other tools.
So I hope to navigate to the desired url using current chrome tab.
Right now I got a solution, that is to send WM_COPYDATA, in which the mhtml file name is passed, to Autohotkey window. In the Autohotkey window, I have the webview2.dll embedded to render the mhtml file.
So that everytime I change the selection in Excel, the corresponding mhtml file will shown in the Autohotkey window, without losing the focus and switching back and force.

here is the code:

**VBA code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindowVisible Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long

Public Type CopyDataStruct
    dwData As LongPtr
    cbData As Long
    lpData As LongPtr
End Type
Private Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Function GetHiddenWinHwndByTitle(strWinTitle) As Long
    Dim lhWndP As Long
    If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, strWinTitle) = True Then
        GetHiddenWinHwndByTitle = lhWndP
    Else
        GetHiddenWinHwndByTitle = 0
    End If
End Function


Sub TC_SendUserCMD(strPath)
    Dim UserCMD As String
    Dim AcWorkbookName As String
    AcWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    
    UserCMD = "em_SelectFile " & strPath & "|" & AcWorkbookName
    
    Dim cds As CopyDataStruct, result As LongPtr
    Static hwndAHKInterposer As Long
    Dim wParam As Long
    wParam = 0
    hwndAHKInterposer = 0
    If (hwndAHKInterposer > 0) Then
        hwndAHKInterposer = hwndAHKInterposer
    Else
        hwndAHKInterposer = GetHiddenWinHwndByTitle("TC-VBA-Interposer")
        Debug.Print 1
    End If
    'Debug.Print hwndAHKInterposer
    If (hwndAHKInterposer > 0) Then
        cds.dwData = Asc("E") + 256 * Asc("M")
        cds.cbData = Len(UserCMD) * 2 + 2  'The size, in bytes
        cds.lpData = StrPtr(UserCMD)
        result = SendMessage(hwndAHKInterposer, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, cds)
        'Debug.Print hwndAHKInterposer
    End If
End Sub



Private Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean
    'https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-locate-the-window-using-findwindow-function-in-windowapi-using-vba
    Dim lhWndP As Long
    Dim sStr As String
    GetHandleFromPartialCaption = False
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
        sStr = Left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
        If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 Then
            GetHandleFromPartialCaption = True
            lWnd = lhWndP
            Debug.Print sStr
            Exit Do
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop
End Function
```

**Autohotkey code**

```
#Include D:\SoftX\AHK_Scripts_V2\UIA-v2-main\Lib\UIA.ahk
#include D:\SoftX\AHK_Scripts_V2\WebView2.ahk
; https://github.com/thqby/ahk2_lib/blob/master/WebView2/WebView2.ahk
; https://github.com/Descolada/UIA-v2/
Persistent
main := Gui() 
main.Title := "TC-VBA-Interposer"
main.SetFont("S14")
main.OnEvent("Close", _exit_)

ctl:=main.Add("GroupBox", "y+10 w700 h500", "ThisGroup")
main.Show()
ctl.wvc := wvc := WebView2.create(ctl.Hwnd)
wv := wvc.CoreWebView2
ctl.nwr := wv.NewWindowRequested(NewWindowRequestedHandler)
TC_Interposer()
return 
TC_Interposer()
{    ;https://wincmd.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=110848&sid=0dfde01723b39e508e96d62c00a7a9b5
    OnMessage(0x4a, TC_Receive_WM_COPYDATA1)  ; 0x4a is WM_COPYDATA          
}

TC_Receive_WM_COPYDATA1(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd)
{  
    PtrPos:=NumGet(lParam + A_PtrSize * 2,0,"Ptr")
    retVal:=StrGet(PtrPos)
    if(retVal)
        ForwardCMD(retVal) 
}

ForwardCMD(strCMD)
{
    if(InStr(strCMD,"em_SelectFile")=1)
    {
        NewCMD:=SubStr(strCMD,StrLen("em_SelectFile")+1)
        NewCMD:=Trim(NewCMD)
        NewCMDArr:=StrSplit(NewCMD, "|")
        FilePath:=NewCMDArr[1]
        if(FileExist(FilePath))
        {
            wv.Navigate("file:///" . FilePath)
        }
    }
}
_exit_(*) {
    ExitApp()
}

NewWindowRequestedHandler(handler, wv2, arg) {
    argp := WebView2.NewWindowRequestedEventArgs(arg)
    deferral := argp.GetDeferral()
    main.GetClientPos(,,&w,&h)
    ctl.wvc := WebView2.create(ctl.Hwnd, ControllerCompleted_Invoke, WebView2.Core(wv2).Environment)
    return 0
    ControllerCompleted_Invoke(wvc) {
        argp.NewWindow := wv := wvc.CoreWebView2
        ctl.nwr := wv.NewWindowRequested(NewWindowRequestedHandler)
        deferral.Complete()
    }
}
```