# Using Cutsom Colors For Charts and Tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

So I have been tasked with creating this.

[image]

I have the charts in the tablix and I have created a custom pallete that is not implemented yet, this is just the sea green pallete, but I need to color the rectangles in the description so they match the charts like this.

[image]

I am thinking maybe a code function that looks at the row and assigns color dynamically the only problem is there is not a static number of rows and the description columns will not always be the same.

Just looking for some ideas thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a Code Function that accepts the series/row name and returns the color (as a string). I would probably code it as one big "Select Case True" statement, e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/794091/1787137

Within each Case statement I would code for the variations in the description columns, using Like or .Contains.

Comment: Excellent suggestion thank you. I did do one thing to make it easier added DENSE_RANK to my sql query so that the SELECT CASE function was easier to write but this got me home. Thank you.