# Input box and null string values

Tags: vba, excel

For the following input box, why does the "case" statement not evaluate but the "If" does? I've declared strInputVal  as a string.

```
strInputVal = InputBox("How many payments?")
```

This works:

```
 If strInputVal = ""   
 Then GoTo Exit_sub  
 End If
```

Below does not work:

```
Select Case IsNumeric(strInputVal)
     Case strInputVal = vbNullString
         GoTo Exit_sub
     End select
```

Comment: your case statement is incorrect.  The case statement equats the select case statement.  so what your select case isnumeric(strinputval) will return either a true or a false.  Those what you case statement should be looking for. case true or case false.  change to select case strinputval and case vbnullstring.  Se my answer below

Answer (score 0):

the case statement should read

```
Select Case strInputVal
    case vbnullString
        GoTo Exit_sub
end select
```

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled upon a unique syntax for `Select Case`

I think of it as [Select Case True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/794036/1316573). It is an alternate to the `If..else if` structure.

With this syntax each case is evaluated to a Boolean and compared to the Boolean which you provide.

So doing some of the evaluations, your code is equivalent to this:

```
Select Case False
   Case "" = vbNullString ' skipped because not False
     GoTo Exit_Sub
End Select
```

I think what you meant to do is the more standard case syntax:

```
Select case strInputVal
  case vbEmptyString
    GoTo Exit_Sub
End Select
```

But you could have written it like this:

```
Select Case True
   Case "" = vbNullString ' not skipped, because true
     GoTo Exit_Sub
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.