# Loop without Do error despite if statements being properly closed

Tags: loops, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm getting the error "Loop without do".
I can't figure out why since all my `if` statements are ended with `end if`.

Maybe you guys can help me to check where it's not closed (if it is not closed)

Here's my code

```
Do until Int(uitgevoerd)=Int(aantal_cat)
    Do until Not IsEmpty(request.form("categorie" & i)) 
        i=i+1
    loop
    Select Case True
        cbvcode = request.form("cbvcode" & i)

        ' Case Instr(cbvcode, "cbvcode") > 0
        if Instr(cbvcode, "cbvcode") > 0 then
            'objConProjecten.Execute(finanSQL)
            uitgevoerd=uitgevoerd+1 
            i=i+1   
        else
            bedragdeelnemer = request.form("bedragdeelnemer"& i)
            cat_id = request.form("categorie" & i)
            huidig_cat_id = request.form("huidig_cat_id_" & i)
            volgnummer = request.form("volgnummer" & i)
            'cbvcode = request.form("cbvcode" & i)

            'kijk of bedragdeelnemer leeg is. Zoniet doe een update of een insert.
            if bedragdeelnemer = "" then
                bedragdeelnemer = 0
            end if

            FOR c=1 to 5
                if Int(categorieen(c))=Int(cat_id) then
                    catgebruikt = TRUE 
                    categorieen(c)=null
                end if
            NEXT        
            response.write("<br>")
            response.write(i)
            response.write("<br>")
            if catgebruikt then
                finanSQL =  _
                    "UPDATE intakeformulieren_financien " & _
                    "SET bedragdeelnemer=" & replace(bedragdeelnemer, ",", ".") & _
                        ", volgnummer=" & volgnummer & _
                        ", cbvcode='" & cbvcode & _
                        "' WHERE formuliernr = " & formnummer & _
                        " AND cat_id = " & cat_id
                        response.write(finanSQL)
                        catgebruikt = FALSE
            else
                finanSQL =  _
                    "INSERT INTO " & _
                    "intakeformulieren_financien (formuliernr, bedragdeelnemer, cat_id, volgnummer, cbvcode) " & _
                    "VALUES ("& & _
                         formnummer & "," & _
                         replace(bedragdeelnemer, ",", ".") & "," & _
                         cat_id & "," & _
                         volgnummer & ",'" & _
                         cbvcode & "')"
                response.write(finanSQL)
            end if
            objConProjecten.Execute(finanSQL)
            uitgevoerd=uitgevoerd+1 
            i=i+1
        end if
Loop
```

Comment: It doesn't help that your code isn't properly indented.

Comment: Your problem is that there's a `Select Case True` in there without an `End Select` or any `Case` statements within.  Try removing that first, and please, *please* format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it in the end. And it works :) Thanks!

```
Do until Int(uitgevoerd)=Int(aantal_cat)
    Do until Not IsEmpty(request.form("categorie" & i)) 
        i=i+1
    loop
    cbvcode = request.form("cbvcode" & i)
    Select Case True

    Case Instr(cbvcode, "-1") > 0
        'objConProjecten.Execute(finanSQL)
        uitgevoerd=uitgevoerd+1 
        i=i+1   
    Case else
       ...
       ...
    End Select
Loop
```

Comment: That is not how you use `Select Case`. Replace it with an `If..Then..Else`.

Comment: Ansgar : you beat me up. This is one of the cases where Select case true is overkill.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The thing about `Select Case` over `If` is it's easy to extend into a multiple outcome scenario. Yes I know you can use `ElseIf` but prefer not to.

Comment: @Lankymart Each of the three control structures is intended for a different scenario. Just because you *can* abuse them to work in other scenarios doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That is your opinion *(I wouldn't call it abuse though)*. It is a [contentious issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/794036/692942) *(linked article is very interested with arguments for and against, not strictly VBScript but it still applies)* some prefer `Select Case True` while others prefer `ElseIf` personally I'm in the `Select Case True` camp. Unless there is some performance reason why using `Select Case True` is bad or a compelling argument not to use it then I'd reconsider.

Comment: Ideally though I will use `Select Case <expression>` rather then `Select Case True` when the situation warrants it.

Comment: @Lankymart Let's agree to disagree. I don't think SO isn't the right place for an extended discussion of this matter.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers thank you. I'm not following it anyway.

Comment: @Lankymart: The primary argument for `Select Case True` in the article you posted was readability. Even then, when I first saw the construct used like it was, I had to read over it a few times to make sure I'd got the gist of it. So even readability comes at a slight cost. Everyone knows what an `If...ElseIf...End If` statement is and why it's there. And it just feels plain wrong to do it like this, as if you're moving the comparison emphasis away from the actual `Select Case` line and into the `Case` statements (hence the loose abuse).

Comment: @BennyNiemeijer: Perhaps you have the wrong handle on what this site actually is. The whole point of SO is to discuss the best options for *other* readers, not just you. Please don't be so rude.

Comment: @Paul Seems to be more and more of them recently.

Answer (score -2):

This is a problem :

```
    finanSQL =  "INSERT INTO intakeformulieren_financien (formuliernr, bedragdeelnemer, cat_id, volgnummer, cbvcode) " &_
                "VALUES ("& formnummer & "," & replace(bedragdeelnemer, ",", ".") & "," & cat_id & "," & volgnummer & ",'" & cbvcode & "')"
```

because you have "&_" instead of "&  _". The underscore MUST be isolated. It probably breaks things in your code.

The other problem I see is your *Select Case True*. I love *Select Case true*, but you don't have anything behind that makes use of it. You don't have any *end select*, neither any *Case* that isn't commented out. Try deleting the whole line.

And try again, post your new code, and tell us if it still does not work. Ah, and please make a better indentation.

Comment: Select Case True is basically bad practice.

Comment: Thanks! You helpt me a lot. I'm not very into classic ASP jet, but I needed to adjust this piece of code for my internship.
In the end I did make use of the _select case true_ I just didn't know much about _select case_ jet so my hole code was a mess.. See my answer to how I did it.

Comment: In reference to `Select Case True`, you simply need to be aware that, unlike C like languages, where you have a `break` to exit out of the associated `case`, you don't with VB Script. With VB Script the first occurrence of the given condition is accepted. So, if you have several complex `Case` statements all evaluating to true, make sure you get them a. in the right order, and b. in the right `Case` statement!

Comment: Select case True is a bad practice when misapplied(when a simple if or a simple Select Case could do the job, both solutions covering most cases). But when you have to follow a decision list, in a specific order, with exotic & non-homogenic data access, it's a readable way to follow the specs. Here, specifically, there is no need.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z: I have to say that I agree with Ansgar Wiechers in his comments above - `Select Case` has its place and it shouldn't be abused.  I have used `Select Case True` before and can appreciate its readability factor, however, I prefer `If...Then..ElseIf` structures.

Comment: @Paul The key here is choice but to say it's abuse I feel is a step too far. Like I said to Ansgar if there was some tangible argument for not using it I would consider it.

Comment: Just a quick comment about the answer to. The first part is nonsense having `&_` works fine, personally I prefer a space but it is not a code breaker.