# C# 7 switch/case using "when" the way it's not meant to be used

Tags: switch-statement, c#-7.0

I've started using this format of `switch` statement. It works, but is there a purist view that the following is bad practice? On the plus side it can be a lot more readable than deeply nested `if` statements. On the downside, I don't think it is meant to be used like this:

```
int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
string timeWord;

switch ("ignore")
{
    case string x when hour < 12:
        timeWord = "morning";
        break;

    case string x when hour < 18:
        timeWord = "afternoon";
        break;

    case string x when hour < 24:
        timeWord = "evening";
        break;

    default:
        throw new LogicException("Another fine mess you got us into");
}

Console.WriteLine("Good {timeWord}");
```

In terms of `default` I prefer defensive programming. I don't like using defaults as a catch-all. Impossible thing happen with amazing regularity. (ref: HHGTTG) The real question though is the (mis/ab)use of `case`.

**EDIT UPDATE** + Further update as I screwed up a cut and paste

It was suggested I post an example I has put in a comment. Here is a different one. There is an if-then example followed by a case. In no way are they meant to be the same, just to show what I meant about the clarity of nested ifs.

```
public class example
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    bool B1, B2, B3, B4, B5;
    static bool GetBool() { return rnd.Next(1) == 0 ? false : true; }
    bool Accept() { return GetBool(); }
    bool Decline() { return GetBool(); }
    List<bool?> nullBools = new List<bool?> { false, true, null };
    bool? Other() { return nullBools[rnd.Next(2)]; }
    void MaybeException() { }
    public example()
    {
        // I don't think it is difficult to miss the holes in this logic
        B1 = GetBool(); B2 = GetBool(); B3 = GetBool(); B4 = GetBool();
        if (B1 && B2)
        {
            if (B3)
                if (B4 & B5)
                    if (!Accept() & !Decline())
                        Other();
                    else
                        Decline();
                else
                if (B4 & !B5)
                    if (B1)
                        Decline();
                    else
                        Accept();
                else
                    MaybeException();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!B1 && B2)
                if (B5 & B4)
                    if (!Accept() && Other() != null)
                        Decline();
                    else
                    {
                        if (!Other() == null)
                            if (!Accept())
                                Decline();
                            else
                                Decline();
                    }
                else
                {
                    if (B4 && !B5)
                        Accept();
                    else
                            if (Other() == null)
                        if (!Accept())
                            Decline();
                    Decline();
                }
        }
        // As opposed to

        switch ("IGNORE")
        {
            case string B_0234 when !B1 && !B2 && B3 && B4:
            case string B_1200 when B1 && B2 && !B3 && !B4:
            case string B_1204 when B1 && B2 && !B3 && B4:
            case string B_1234 when B1 && B2 && B3 && B4:
                if (Other() == null)
                    Accept();
                break;

            case string B_0004 when !B1 && !B2 && !B3 && B4:
            case string B_0134 when B1 && !B2 && B3 && B4:
            case string B_1000 when B1 && !B2 && !B3 && !B4:
            case string B_1030 when B1 && !B2 && B3 && !B4:
            case string B_1203 when B1 && B2 && B3 && !B4:
            case string B_1004 when B1 && !B2 && !B3 && B4:  // Compile error duplicate
                if (Other() == null)
                    if (!Accept())
                        Decline();

            case string B_0230 when !B1 && B2 && B3 && !B4:
            case string B_1201 when B1 && B2 && !B3 && B4:
            case string B_1230 when B1 && B2 && B3 && !B4:
                MaybeException();
                break;

            //case string B_0101 when !B1 && B2 && !B3 && B4:
            //case string B_0000 when !B1 && !B2 && !B3 && !B4:

            default:
                throw new Exception("Whoops missed the two above impossible??");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's a good thing that [`select case true`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/794036/11683) has made it to C#. Opinion-based otherwise.

Comment: "*I've started using this format of `switch` statement*". Hopefully the novelty will wear off very soon and you'll then stop. You are making your code unnecessarily hard to read. Why do that?

Comment: @DavidArno I've tried it both ways. Well each to their. Once you have seen it a couple of times it makes sense. I remember seeing the ternary operator ?: for the first time about 30 years ago and thought it ugly. I use it all the time now, but if you come from some other languages it looks weird.

Comment: Well, the updated example is not really fare in comparing the approaches. The `switch` looks neat because it forms a rectangular block, but it only forms it because each `case` mentions all four `B`s. Yes, it is easier to follow, but it would be equally easy to have blocks of `||`'ed `if`s where each condition also mentions all four `B`s.

Comment: I agree. But I didn't have to use all four Bs. But it still catches the missed 'cases'

Answer (score 3):

I personally, wouldn't use such a construct - it is confusing, in particularly given that the object your are supposedly switching on isn't involved in the switching.

In your particular example, switching on `hour` would be much more natural.

A sequence of `if` statements (with `return`s) would read more naturally to me.

Alternatively, a dictionary, mapping `hour` with the return string could work well.

Comment: Switching on `hour` or having a dictionary would require listing all possible values for `hour` explicitly.

Comment: @GSerg - not really. Not if you use the dictionary keys in a predicate (less then, more than and combinations). In the dictionary they are just data - how you use the data is up to you. Also, switching on hour in conjunction with `when` (as current code does) will work.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for your reply. The example is simplistic. But it works for state-based decisions. If what you are about to do next depends on (say) 4 variables and certain combinations are illegal/impossible its a lot easier to read than 4 level nested if statements. More importantly it's easier to find what combination you have missed . You get an exception. Each to there own. One last thing, switching on hour doesn't allow:  case string x: when Today="Monday" && moonState ==MoonState.Gibbous && CloudCover<0.3. I better shut-up. I'm sounding defensive and I'm here for opinions.

Comment: @DigiFriend Thank you for your reply. The example is simplistic. But it works for state-based decisions. If what you are about to do next depends on (say) 4 variables and certain combinations are illegal/impossible its a lot easier to read than 4 level nested if statements. More importantly it's easier to find what combination you have missed . You get an exception. Each to there own. One last thing, switching on hour doesn't allow:  case string x: when Today="Monday" && moonState ==MoonState.Gibbous && CloudCover<0.3. I better shut-up. I'm sounding defensive and I'm here for opinions.

Comment: @GSerg Sorry - meant to reply to digifriend and I went past the 5 minute timeout for edits

Comment: @Paulustrious You might want to add this other example to your question. If there is any important info that can make your question clearer, you are always encouraged to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44096614/edit) it.

Comment: @anatolyg Added an example as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Compare it to the `if-else` structure, which has always been available:

```
if (hour < 12)
{
    timeWord = "morning";
}
else if (hour < 18)
{
    timeWord = "afternoon";
}
else if (hour < 24)
{
    timeWord = "evening";
}
else
{
    throw new LogicException("Another fine mess you got us into");
}
```

The latter code has pretty much the same structure, allows extending the conditions, and supports the last catch-all `else` part.

It doesn't have the `"ignore"` part, which might be confusing at first:

> What exactly is being ignored here?
>
> ... Oh, it's the string `"ignore"` itself!

So what's the advantages of the `case` code structure? I could think of these:

- `case` makes it clear that you want to check various values of some "main" variable, which may be modified by other variables. While `if-else` has pretty generic conditions.
- If you are obliged to put braces `{}` around if-else code clauses, the `switch` code may become shorter

These advantages don't look strong to me.