# How to add error message inside multiples if conditions

Tags: vba

It's probably an easy one but I'm kinda new to programming. I probably did some hard-coding beceause I don't know any better.

I would like to add an error message if the first `If` statement isn't met. I will give you a simplified example of my code. If you want the actual code, let me know and I will edit my question (but careful, it's long!)

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True and CheckBox2.Value = False then 

(CODE number 1)

Else
MsgBox ("error")
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = False and CheckBox2.Value = True then

(CODE numer 2)

Else
MsgBox("Error")
End if
```

The problem here is that the `If` statements keeps coming and the code will run line by line. I am aware of that. But I just don't know any better. So I can't place any msgbox error because the code will keep running and execute the rest.

How Do I fragment theses lines so I can place any messagebox I want for each blocks of `if` ?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: When I used MsgBox between `Else` and the `Exit Sub`, nothing happens! If I dont respect the `If` Statement, and click the button to generate the number on my form, nothing happens. No number get generate, but no error message appears neither. @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: I'm completely lost now! Thanks anwyays for the clues! @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: Forget what I said earlier, you completely changed your code to be something drastically different than what first appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condense that into an `If...ElseIf...End If` statement.

```vb
If CheckBox1.Value = True and CheckBox2.Value = False then 

(CODE number 1)

ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False and CheckBox2.Value = True then

(CODE numer 2)

Else
MsgBox("Error")
End if
```

This will check the first statement, and if it evaluates as true, it'll do `(CODE number 1)`. If it's not true, it'll check to see if the second statement is true. If the second statement is true, it'll do `(CODE number 2)`. If the second statement isn't true, it'll do `MsgBox("Error")`

If you have a BUNCH of these, you can do a `Select Case True` [workaround, but it's generally not advised.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794036/select-case-true)

Comment: I have a bunch of these... but your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!