# If multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, criteria

I am currently working on a multiple if, I would like to avoid writing 100 "OR" in my code and therefore I have a list of criterias (AO450 to AO515) and I would like to have something like this : If the cells(i, 33) like one of the criterias, then "comment", your help would be very welcomed :)

```vb
Sub MultipleIf()

    For i = 3 To 467
    
        If Cells(i, 19).Value > 5000 Then
            If Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "Cells(AO450:AO515).Value" & "*" Then
               Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentA"
            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "ABC" & "*" Then
                Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentB"
            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "DEF" & "*" Then
                Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentC"
            Else
               Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentD"
            End If   
        
        ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Value < -5000 Then
            If Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "Cells(AO450:AO515).Value" & "*" Then
               Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentAA"
            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Value < 0 And Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "ABC" & "*" Then
                Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentBB"
            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Value < 0 And Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "DEF" & "*" Then
                Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentC"
            Else
               Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentD"
            End If
        
        Else:
            If Cells(i, 19).Value < 0 And Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "GHI" & "*" Then
                Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentE"
                Cells(i, 36).Value = "commentF"
            Else
                Cells(i, 35).Value = "commentD"
            End If
       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It may be tedious to create but in a situation like this I'd be putting the values in AO450 to AO515 into an arraylist (to use contains) or dictionary as keys (to use exists), however its not clear from your post what the impact of the  * either side of your ranges will be , e.g. how much do they complicate the number of values you have to accommodate.  Can you provide some example data for us to look at.

Comment: FYI you already tested for `Cells(i, 19).Value > 5000` so no need to test for `Cells(i, 19).Value > 0` in the nested `If` block

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - updated to add full (reworked) code

If you want to test whether a value is found in a single-column range then you can do something like this:

```vb
Sub MultipleIf()
    'come up with some better variable names than `v19` and `v33`...
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, rw As Range, v19, v33 As String, rngList As Range, txt
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngList = ws.Range("AO450:AO515")
    
    For i = 3 To 467
        Set rw = ws.Rows(i)
        v19 = rw.Cells(19).Value
        v33 = rw.Cells(33).Value
        txt = ""
        
        If v19 > 5000 Then
            Select Case True 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794036/select-case-true
                Case ColumnContains(rngList, v33): txt = "commentA"
                Case v33 Like "*ABC*": txt = "commentB"
                Case v33 Like "*DEF*": txt = "commentC"
                Case Else: txt = "commentD"
            End Select
        ElseIf v19 < -5000 Then
            Select Case True
                Case ColumnContains(rngList, v33): txt = "commentAA"
                Case v33 Like "*ABC*": txt = "commentBB"
                Case v33 Like "*DEF*": txt = "commentC"
                Case Else: txt = "commentD"
            End Select
        Else
            If v19 < 0 And v33 Like "*GHI*" Then
                txt = "commentE"
                rw.Cells(36).Value = "commentF"
            Else
                txt = "commentD"
            End If
       End If
       If Len(txt) > 0 Then rw.Cells(35).Value = txt
    Next

End Sub

'does a (single-column) range `rng` contain the string `txt`?
Function ColumnContains(rng As Range, txt As String) As Boolean
    ColumnContains = Not IsError(Application.Match("*" & txt & "*", rng, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure that your solution fits my issue : I have text in column 33, and want to check if for each cell of column 33, I have common text with one of the cells of Array AO450:AO515 (in column 33, the word I need to match with the AO Array is surrounded by other text, thats why I used Like"*word*"), maybe I should put all data of AO Array in one cell ?

Comment: To be more precise, lets say that in column 33 I have data like this : xzx Word1 wqsq ; xzez Word2 xzxz ; dzc Word3 zd and in AO Array I have Word2 ; Word1; Word3

Comment: @httpsuser0000 To apply this, `If Cells(i, 33).Value Like "*" & "Cells(AO450:AO515).Value" & "*" Then` becomes `If ColumnContains(Range("AO450:AO515"), Cells(i, 33).Value) Then`