VBA Excel HTMLBody doesn't work for different values
I want to prepare the automatic email reply based on various values in the column.
I've prepared the Case, although it seems like it doesn't work. Despite no error, nothing is shown in Outlook as the HTMLBody.
My code looks like this:
Dim workb As Workbook

Dim Lr As Long
Dim n As Long

Dim SRef As Range, BlM As Range, SNR As Range, ObjN As Range
Dim Target As Range
Dim SelectedRow As Long

Dim BlmM1 As String, BlmM2 As String

Set workb = ThisWorkbook
Set vmg = workb.Sheets("A55")

Set Target = ActiveCell

SelectedRow = Target.Row

Set SRef = vmg.Range("A" & SelectedRow)
Set BlM = vmg.Range("C" & SelectedRow)
Set SNR = vmg.Range("K" & SelectedRow)
Set ObjN = vmg.Range("H" & SelectedRow)



'Preparing email format

BlmM1 = (Left(BlM, 1))
BlmM2 = Split(BlM, " ")(1)


Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


'EMAIL GENERATOR

Dim ans
ans = MsgBox("Are you ready to report this job", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If ans = vbYes Then
With OutlookMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    
    Select Case ObjN
        Case ObjN.Value = "Gifted Chamber"
            .HTMLBody = "AAA" & SRef & " " & BlM
        Case ObjN.Value Like "*Blockage"
            .HTMLBody = "BBB" & SRef & " " & BlM
        Case ObjN.Value = "D-Pole"
            .HTMLBody = "CCC" & SRef & " " & BlM
        Case ObjN.Value = "Non Policy D-Pole"
            .HTMLBody = "DDD" & SRef & " " & BlM
    End Select
    
    .To = xxxxxxx@gmail.com
    .CC = yyyyy@gmail.com
    .Subject = SRef & " - Order report"
End With
Else
Exit Sub

End If

It doesn't appear that you're creating (valid) HTML

I create just HTMLbody as the email content. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with cases, as it comes up blank.

.HTMLBody requires that you pass valid HTML. Perhaps you want .Body.

Alright, does it mean, that I have to bound the entire email into the case?

That Select Case looks wrong?   Try Select Case True

Your Case expressions are all evaluating to a Boolean, so you need Select Case True
See for example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794036/select-case-true
